# how to run multiple ansible plays in parallel?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook with multiple plays:

```
---
- hosts: druid-realtime-1
  sudo: true
  roles:
  - { role: druid-realtime, du_rt_id: 1 }

- hosts: druid-realtime-2
  sudo: true
  roles:
  - { role: druid-realtime, du_rt_id: 2 }
```

How do I tell ansible to run both plays in parallel instead of one after another?

Comment: You can't, but please explain why would you need to?

Comment: Question can be better phrased as - "How to process multiple hosts for same role in parallel?".  The current question is way more generic and answers present here do not address the generic requirement.

Comment: @Mxx: Typically to speed up bootstrapping.  Typically there is site.yaml or main.yaml which includes many other unrelated playbooks.  If all these unrelated playbooks could be executed in parallel without requiring shell features for fork/background, then it would be great.

Answer (score 9):

You could do it this way

In your Ansible inventory, group your servers and assign a host variable:

```
[druid-realtime]
druid-realtime-1 id=1
druid-realtime-2 id=2
```

Then reference the variable in the playbook:

```
- hosts: druid-realtime
  sudo: true
  roles: 
    - { role: druid-realtime, du_rt_id: {{ id }} }
```

Comment: Surely those mismatched delimiters are accidental?

Comment: What is du_rt_id? Is that an Ansible built-in keyword?

Comment: just an arbitrary variable. See examples in http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_roles.html#roles

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this was possible when this post was created but I believe this is what you were looking for:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_async.html

This allows you to stop the task from blocking, ie. waiting for the task to complete before progressing onto the next task.

Comment: (Besides that that doc link is bit-rotted,) I think that's not what OP is looking for. That would be for stopping the _task_ from blocking (basically, in Bash-ese, adding a `&` to the end of the task). But what we want is to execute two _plays_ in parallel — one group of hosts executing `task1a; task2a; task3a` in serial, _while_ a disjoint group of hosts executes `task1b; task2b` in serial.

Answer (score 0):

To run multiple playbooks in parallel I wrote [ansible-parallel](https://pypi.org/project/ansible-parallel/) today.

So for your question, split the plays in different yml files and run:

```
pip install ansible-parallel
ansible-parallel *.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here is my playbook:

```yaml
- name: Upgrade Debian-family machines
  hosts: dist_debian
  roles:
    - role: tobias-richter.apt_upgrade
      apt_upgrade: "full"

- name: Upgrade DietPi machines
  hosts: dist_dietpi
  pre_tasks:
    - name: DietPi distribution update
      raw: /boot/dietpi/dietpi-update
  roles:
    - role: tobias-richter.apt_upgrade
      apt_upgrade: "full"
```

It should manage some Debian machines, but some of them are DietPi (Raspberry Pi) machines which are part of the Debian OS family. So, DietPi has `apt` available, but it wants me to use the dedicated `dietpi-update` tool before-hand. `dietpi-update` will update DietPi specific files and run `apt update`, but not `apt upgrade`. So I couldn't just give all machines the `apt_upgrade` role, but I didn't want DietPi to block upgrading on other Debian machines.

One solution is to group all hosts into one (I called `os_deb`) and use conditions instead:

```yaml
- name: Upgrade Debian machines
  hosts: os_deb
  strategy: free
  pre_tasks:
    - name: DietPi distribution update
      raw: /boot/dietpi/dietpi-update
      when: "'dist_dietpi' in group_names"
  roles:
    - role: tobias-richter.apt_upgrade
      apt_upgrade: "full"
```

I also have to use the `free` strategy, so that it would not wait for the `pre_tasks` to finish on all hosts before continuing with the roles.

For reference, here is my inventory:

```ini
[dist_dietpi]
kronprinz.lan

[dist_debian]
xmind

# debian based
[os_deb:children]
dist_debian
dist_dietpi
```

Answer (score -3):

If your plays are isolated, you can split your playbook : 1 play -> 1 playbook. For example:

- *druid-realtime-1.yml*:

`- hosts: druid-realtime-1
   sudo: true
   roles:
   - { role: druid-realtime, du_rt_id: 1 }`

- *druid-realtime-2.yml*:

`- hosts: druid-realtime-2
   sudo: true
   roles:
   - { role: druid-realtime, du_rt_id: 2 }`

- Keep a main playbook *site.yml* that includes other playbooks:

`- include: druid-realtime-1.yml
- include: druid-realtime-2.yml`

With this approach, you can use a terminal for each playbooks and continue to use your main playbook.

Comment: This does not solve the issue at hand, running it in parallel on both hosts.